# Xcode Sqlite Sequence Error In Writing

Tags: database, xcode, ipad, sqlite

I created a SQLite database that currently has only one table. I connected it to Xcode, made the all required steps, and found a problem in writing my files.

My table has 5 items (primary key, name, birth date, college name, course name).

While saving my data, it says:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Error while creating add statement. 'library routine called out of sequence''

I set breakpoints and found where the problem is, but I just can't solve it.

```
-(void)saveStudentInfo{

sqlite3_stmt *statement = NULL;


    const char *sql = "insert into studentInfo (name,collegeName,courseName) Values (?, ?, ?)";

    if (sqlite3_open("my_db_filename.db", &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        //sqlite3_stmt *addStmt;

        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &addStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating add statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        } else {
            // do things with addStmt, call sqlite3_step
            sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 1, [studentName UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 3, [studentCollegeName UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 4, [studentCourseName UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

            if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(addStmt))
                NSAssert1(0, @"Error while inserting data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
            else
                studentID = sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(database);

            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        }
        sqlite3_close(database);     
    }


if (sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_DONE){
    UIAlertView *error = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Done" message:@"Files were added to database" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [error show];
}
else {
    UIAlertView *error = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"StudentOrganizer could not add database" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [error show];
}
```

Comment: How do you get the database variable?

Comment: for now just for testing i've set strings of those variables. But the plan is to get values from textfield inside tableviewcell. Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: The only difference I can see between your code & mine (which works fine) is your use of SQLITE_TRANSIENT in the bindings, as opposed to NULL, but I'd be surprised if that made a difference. As CBredlow asked, are you sure you've set up the database properly? It's always helpful to use a SQLite tool of some sort to check your databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot to open the database before calling sqlite3_prepare_v2.

A good way to do it is like this:

```
sqlite3* database;
if (sqlite3_open("my_db_filename.db", &database) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    sqlite3_stmt *addStmt;

    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &addStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating add statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    } else {
        // do things with addStmt, call sqlite3_step
        sqlite3_finalize(sqlStatement);
    }
    sqlite3_close(database);     
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the error solution, but the other problem is that now doesn't write to database.. :/ I edited the previous code

Comment: Do you still get the 'library routine called out of sequence' error?